# Reset bootstrap model content when closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i'm looking for a way that when a user is closing my model it resets all the data he did put in. Example it uncheck the input he did check.

I'm looking for a jquery sulution if that's possible.

Code

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Insert your information!</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Summoner Name:</h4>
                        <input type="text" />
                        <br /><br />
                        <h4>Select boosting methode</h4>
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" />SoloQ
                            <input id="DuoQCheckbox" type="checkbox" />DuoQ
                        </span>
                        <br />(We add +25% to the final price for DuoQ)
                        <br /><br />
                        <h4>Select your region</h4>
                        <select>
                            <option></option>
                            <option>EUW (Europe West)</option>
                            <option>EUNE (Europe Nordic & East)</option>
                            <option>NA (North America)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <a>Buy now</a>
                            total
                            <span id="priceCheckout"></span>
                            $
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can modify the action with these

hide.bs.modal   This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.

hidden.bs.modal This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e)

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

JS:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('form')[0].reset();
});
```

This code reset the form when you close the modal.

### [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVRORr)